# Modify xml attribute value Android

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml like this in the `raw` folder

```
<premios>
    <premio
        corazones="5000"
        nombrerecurso="foto"
        carpetarecurso="drawable"
        tipo="imagen"
        abierto="yes"
        />
    <premio
        corazones="6000"
        nombrerecurso="cuak"
        carpetarecurso="raw"
        tipo="audio"
        abierto="no"
    />
    <premio
        corazones="7000"
        nombrerecurso="video"
        carpetarecurso="raw"
        tipo="video"
        abierto="no"
    />
    <premio
        corazones="7000"
        nombrerecurso="video"
        carpetarecurso="raw"
        tipo="video"
        abierto="yes"
    />
</premios>
```

I read it on the `OnCreate` of the `activity` and with the attribute `abierto` I am building a `List<Boolean>` (`yes->true`, `no->false`).

The thing is that while the `Activity` is running, the list may be modified and some `false` may become `true`.

So, when the `Activity` is Stopped, I would want this changes to be saved, modifying in the `XML` the attributes "`abierto`" where "no" becomes "yes".

Comment: You can't! Use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the the best solution here is use SQLite.

Create a table named premios like this, and use it to read, store, and modify values:

```
CREATE TABLE PREMIOS(
   ID                INT PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL,
   CORAZONES         INT,
   NOMBRE_RECURSO    TEXT,
   CARPETA_RECURSO   TEXT,
   TIPO              TEXT,
   ABIERTO           TEXT
);
```

Android developer documentation and a simple example:

> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

**You can not change any Resource file!!**

As mention in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.raw.html) `ids` of files in `Raw` folder stores as `public static final class R.raw` in resource file **R**

So, if you need to change your values in future you should store it in [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)